# In browser javascript ftp or other local file hosting?

Tags: javascript, browser, ftp, hosting, local

Can this be done? If so how and where can I find example code, libraries etc.?

clarification: I mean hoasting an ftp server in browser with js.

Comment: It's hard to see what you're asking. You want to host JS on an FTP server? You want to access FTP with JS? Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, are you tyring to download a file from an FTP server using javascript?

Comment: ok sorry I meant hosting an ftp server in browser with javascript that can be accessed locally also in browser with javascript

Comment: I think what you really mean is that you wish to browse an FTP using JS?

Comment: no what i mean is that the user could host his files with an in browser ftp web app

Comment: and who/what would access them? from where?

Comment: another user (a peer) from a local wifi network

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not something you can do using JavaScript that is executed from a web document.  There is no interface made available to JavaScript programs that could be used to open listening TCP sockets.

You might be able to do this from inside of a browser extension, depending on the particular browser, but you would have to release a different extension for each browser you intend to support.